What does GPGME `verify` reult with 0 (zero) summary mean?
What is the meaning of a GPGME signature result with summary value 0 (zero)?
The GPGME library provides a comprehensive API for GnuPG operations. The verify operation returns (among other things) a collection of signature results derived from the input data. Each signature is of type gpgme_signature_t; that object has a summary attribute, of type gpgme_sigsum_t.
The value of gpgme_sigsum_t is a bitmap structure; the gpgme_signature_t documentation describes all the meanings of those flags.
From my reading of that documentation, zero is not a meaningful gpgme_sigsum_t value; the value should either have the GPGME_SIGSUM_VALID bit set (if the signature is valid), or some other combination of bits should be set. A zero summary (with no bits set) does not seem a possible result from that library.
When I call verify (passing an inline signed data stream, read from a text file), the result is meaningful: no error, the signature results have the expected keys and timestamp etc., but every signature has a summary value of 0.
What does this value mean? How is its meaning different from GPGME_SIGSUM_VALID? How is its meaning different from any other possible summary value?
(If it matters, I am using the Python PyGPGME wrapper; from what I can tell the wrapper is simply exposing the GPGME interface with Python objects, so I believe the questions above are relevant to the underlying C library.)

At a guess: Have you checked the return value of the function you're calling? Maybe it returned an error, which - again, I guess - could mean that the value of those fields is meaningless.
